# If I add databinding to gradle, is it possible to use viewbinding as well?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-databinding, android-viewbinding

I learned today that there is something called `viewbinding` other than `databinding`.

I was new to `viewbinding`, but I was already using it in code.

In other words, I knew it was `data binding` and was using it wrong.

To use `viewbinding` i need to apply below code in gradle. However, I have never applied anything other than data binding.

> `dataBinding { enabled = true }`

However, in my code, it is accessed through the ID of the view with `binding.title.text`-like code.
There is also no `<data>` tag. Isn't this a `view binding`?

***XML***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".fragment.WritingRoutineFragment">
        <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppBarOverlay"
            app:elevation="0dp">
            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/title"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
            </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
        </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
</layout>
```

***WRFragment.kt***

```
class WritingRoutineFragment : Fragment() {
    
    var titleArg: String? = null
    private var _binding: FragmentWritingRoutineBinding? = null
    private val binding get() = _binding!!
    private val viewModel = WriteRoutineViewModel()
    
    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater,
                              container: ViewGroup?,
                              savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        _binding = FragmentWritingRoutineBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        viewModel.setTitle(titleArg)

        viewModel.title.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { titleData ->
            // UI UPDATE
            binding.title.text = titleData // viewbinding? title is TextView ID
        }

        return binding.root
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
viewModel.title.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { titleData ->
            // UI UPDATE
            binding.title.text = titleData // viewbinding? title is TextView ID
        }
```

yes,you are using view binding.

if you want to use data binding ,code will be like

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
 <data>
        <variable
            name="viewModel"
            type="yourpackage.viewmodel" />
    </data>
    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".fragment.WritingRoutineFragment">
        <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppBarOverlay"
            app:elevation="0dp">
            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/title"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:text="@{viewModel.title}"
                    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
            </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
        </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
</layout>
```

Comment: But I didn't add any viewbing code to gradle. But how is viewbinding possible?

Comment: if you enabled databinding ,you no need to enable viewbinding .because databinding has  inbuilt view binding.@ybybyb

Comment: Oh right? By analogy, is it a concept like inheritance?

Answer (score 1):

No, I guess you have to use both. Both provide different functionalities.